# Inconsistency with Highlighting Text from Different Websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, highlight

I am using the following code to highlight the word "and" from the content scripts of my chrome extension.

```
function findText(element, pattern, callback) {
    for (var childi= element.childNodes.length; childi-->0;) {
        var child= element.childNodes[childi];
        if (child.nodeType==1) {
            findText(child, pattern, callback);
        } else if (child.nodeType==3) {
            var matches= [];
            var match;
            while (match= pattern.exec(child.data))
                matches.push(match);
            for (var i= matches.length; i-->0;)
                callback.call(window, child, matches[i]);
        }
    }
}

findText(document.body, /\band\b/g, function(node, match) {
    var span= document.createElement('span');
    span.className= 'highlight';
    node.splitText(match.index+3);
    span.appendChild(node.splitText(match.index));
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(span, node.nextSibling);
});
```

This code successfully highlights the word "and" on pages like wikipedia, but when I navigate to more complicated websites likes espn.com or cnn.com, it fails to highlight the word "and".

I'm guessing there is something wrong with how I am approaching the DOM tree but cannot quiet figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

Highlighting the text on a page via Chrome Extension must be done through a  [*'Content Script'*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). The purpose of the content script is to gather data or make changes to the pages you are browsing using CSS/Javascript. So we need to put *highlight()* functions in a content script.

Here's a sample code for highlight() method:

```
highlight('yellow');
```

In your content script, you need to listen for a request coming from your extension, so that we send it the selected text:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender,  sendResponse) {
if (request.method == "getSelection")
sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
else
sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

Comment: I understand that.  I think the issue I am running into is that my code is encountering an issue with more complicated HTML.  I need to somehow penetrate further into the HTML to find and modify the HTML tags surrounding the text.  If you can help with that it would be much appreciated!